# How to handle JSON with Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to Python. I have a JSON response like this :

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-10-19T08:52:10Z",
}
```

I need to get the value of `Code`, which is `Success`. How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json
# ... you read here from the file
data = '''{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-10-19T08:52:10Z"
}'''
result = json.loads(data)
print result['Code']
```

Be careful with the format!! I removed the comma after `"LastUpdated" : "2012-10-19T08:52:10Z"`, because this is not a valid json.

Answer (score 4):

Search for `json` in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/) . You'll find [the json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) explained, with examples.